# lightbox_me not working on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am very new to this so apologise in advance for offending/upsetting anyone.

I have built my first website (http://www.goodgollyexeter.co.uk). There is a shopping cart on my website (I'm using Plum shop which is working great). I want the user to be able to click the "View Cart" button (in the top right hand corner on the website which has `id="viewcart"`) and then for the contents of their cart to be displayed in a lightbox style window. The contents of their cart is contained within a `<div>` which has `id="cart_holder"`.

To try and achieve the above I am using lightbox_me but I can't get it to work off of the "View Cart" button click event. If I remove the button click event coding then lightbox_me works and displays the contents of the cart but, as there is no event to trigger it, it opens as soon as the page loads. For now I have removed the button click event coding so if you were to visit the website you should see lightbox_me working (but on page load rather then a button click event).

I have tried to pick out the relevant code and show it below. This is the code that I have tried in order to get lightbox_me to work off of the "View Cart" button click event (adapted from lightbox_me website example) but this does not work:

```
<head>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.lightbox_me.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<button id="viewcart" class="viewcart">View Cart</button>

<div id="cart_holder">
<h1> Your Cart </h1>
<p>Currently your cart contains the following items:</p>
<div id="cart"></div>
<label>Items:</label> <span class="cart-quantity">0</span><br>
<label>Sub-Total:</label> <span class="cart-subtotal">£0.00</span><br>
<label>Shipping:</label> <span class="cart-shipping">£0.00</span><br>
<label>Total:</label> <span class="cart-total">£0.00</span><br>
<br>
Please click below to pay using a credit or debit card or via Paypal:
<br>
<br>
<button class="paypal">Checkout</input>
</div>

<script>
$("#viewcart").click(function() {
$("#cart_holder").lightbox_me();
});
</script>

</body>
```

When I add the above code lightbox_me stops working which is really annoying as if I remove the View Cart button click event coding so it reads like this:

```
<script>
$("#cart_holder").lightbox_me();
</script>
```

then lightbox_me works (but only on page load and not on button click event).

I don't know if it is of any use but when I inspected the `<div id="cart_holder">` element in Chrome I did notice the following error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'lightbox_me'
```

Due to my ignorance I'm afraid this means very little to me. If anyone could tell me what I am doing wrong and how to get lightbox_me to work from the "View Cart" button click event I would be very grateful indeed. Please let me know if I can explain anything better or post more code or anything else to better assist. Thanks Alex

Comment: Try to put your script inside `$( document ).ready()` to wait that the DOM is ready (http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: H Fab Sa, thanks for such a quick response. I have tried the following code but still no joy: <script>
 $( document ).ready(function(){
  $("#viewcart").click(function(){
   $("#cart_holder").lightbox_me();
  });
 });
 </script>

Answer (score 0):

Check your last closing button tag for checkout:

```
<button class="paypal">Checkout</input>  <!-- should this close with button and not input? -->
```

Can you wrap your jquery like this?

```
;(function($){  // add 

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#viewcart").button().click(function() {
            $("#cart_holder").lightbox_me();        
        });

    });

})(jQuery);  // add
```

Comment: Hi Darth Jon and thanks for the input. You are right it should have closed with </button> - I have changed accordingly. Still no joy with lightbox_me though. I just don't understand why this works on its own but as soon as i put it in a click event it stops working altogether. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1.  Does the functionality fail in all browsers?

Comment: 2. Try to wrap your jQuery like I have shown above - there may be a conflict with the other client side scripts you are importing.

Comment: 3.  It also looks like from your published site you are trying to load the jquery.js library twice, once before your custom jquery as listed above and once after.